# How do i custom draw of TEdit control text?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'd like to draw a piece of TEdit.Text using Font.Color different from the default. Are there any examples how to do that?

I'm attempting to do something like this:

[image]

<sub>NOTE: what this screenshot pictures is merely a hairy draft, but it convinces me what problem solvable.</sub>

Comment: You are welcome to share your "solution", so we can discuss it, and provide feed-backs (a screenshot is not a solution).

Comment: @kobik, there might be a series of simple questions dedicated to the particular problems i stumbled upon. But this might happen later, currently i'm not stuck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Edit` controls do not have *owner-draw* support, but you can *custom-draw* it by sub-classing it and handling `WM_PAINT` (among many other messages). It's doable, but it would be a world of pain to actually implement 100% correctly. From the docs: [Developing Custom Draw Controls in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364048%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Note that owner-draw will work for most controls. However, **it doesn't work for edit controls**; and with regards to the list control, it works only for report-view style

I was also interested to find out how deep the rabbit hole goes, so,
Here is a code sample using an interposer class (still needs to implement selection but the custom drawing works when the caret is in the control):

```
type
  TEdit = class(StdCtrls.TEdit)
  private
    FCanvas: TCanvas;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    procedure Paint; virtual;
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
    property Canvas: TCanvas read FCanvas;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

...

constructor TEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FCanvas := TControlCanvas.Create;
  TControlCanvas(FCanvas).Control := Self;
end;

destructor TEdit.Destroy;
begin
  FCanvas.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TEdit.Paint;
var
  R: TRect;
  I: Integer;
  S: String;
begin
  R := ClientRect;
  Inc(R.Left, 1);
  Inc(R.Top, 1);
  Canvas.Brush.Assign(Self.Brush);
  Canvas.Font.Assign(Self.Font);
  for I := 1 to Length(Text) do
  begin
    if Text[I] in ['0'..'9'] then
      Canvas.Font.Color := clRed
    else
      Canvas.Font.Color := clGreen;
    S := Text[I];
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), -1, R, DT_LEFT or DT_NOPREFIX or
      DT_WORDBREAK or DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly);
    Inc(R.Left,Canvas.TextWidth(S));
  end;
end;

procedure TEdit.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  FCanvas.Lock;
  try
    FCanvas.Handle := DC;
    try
      TControlCanvas(FCanvas).UpdateTextFlags;
      Paint;
    finally
      FCanvas.Handle := 0;
    end;
  finally
    FCanvas.Unlock;
  end;
end;

procedure TEdit.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  ControlState := ControlState+[csCustomPaint];
  inherited;
  ControlState := ControlState-[csCustomPaint];
end;

procedure TEdit.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited WndProc(Message);
  with Message do
    case Msg of
      CM_MOUSEENTER, CM_MOUSELEAVE, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDOWN,
      WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP,
      WM_SETFOCUS, WM_KILLFOCUS,
      CM_FONTCHANGED, CM_TEXTCHANGED:
      begin
        Invalidate;
      end;
   end; 
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this example is really propels me in my study and points me to numerous nuances i missed completely (eg, csCustomPaint).

Comment: Since you're not using the control's own surface, you have to account for all possible display cases. For instance, other than selection, you also have to account for when text should be displayed beginning with a character other than the first one - for when the text is larger to fit the control and the user has scrolled it through the end. In actuality, what you'll be doing is developing your edit control, not using one!..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I have just used the code provided by kobik, with only changes to how the text is drawn, and all the cases you mention are handled properly. Granted this is 5 years later and on different OS and Delphi version, but as a reference, the above code worked great for what I had to do.

Answer (score 9):

No. A standard tEdit does not have support for custom drawing or having text with multiple colors. As an alternative you can use a tRichEdit with WantReturns=False.

Comment: I agree what adding custom drawing support is a real PITA given what it descends directly from TWinControl, however i've proven what it is pretty doable.

Comment: @user - I'd be surprised if your custom drawing works when the caret is in the control. Does it?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, it would be really bold statement to say what my attempt "works" so far :-) Yet i'm not convinced what this is not doable at all.

Comment: @Mike W, edit controls do not have owner-draw support, but you can custom-draw it by sub-classing it and handling `WM_PAINT` (among many other messages). It's doable, but it would be a world of pain.

Comment: @kobik - agreed.  I should have said "does not have _built-in_ support"

Answer (score 4):

Some improvements to kobik solusion:

```
procedure TMyEdit.Paint;
var
  R: TRect;
  I: Integer;

  NewColor : TColor;
  NewBackColor : TColor;

  procedure DrawEx(S: String);
  begin
     if ((i-1)>=Self.SelStart) and ((i-1)<=(Self.SelStart+(Self.SelLength-1)))
        and (Self.SelLength>0) and (Self.focused)
       then begin
         Canvas.Font.Color  := clWhite;
         Canvas.Brush.Color := NewColor;
       end else begin
         Canvas.Font.Color  := NewColor;
         Canvas.Brush.Color := NewBackColor;
       end;
     Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
     DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), -1, R, DT_LEFT or DT_NOPREFIX or
       DT_WORDBREAK or DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly);
  end;

begin
  R := ClientRect;
  Inc(R.Left, 1);
  Inc(R.Top, 1);
  Canvas.Brush.Assign(Self.Brush);
  Canvas.Font.Assign(Self.Font);

  if Self.Focused then begin
      NewBackColor       := clYellow;
      Canvas.Brush.Color := NewBackColor;
      Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
      Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
      Canvas.DrawFocusRect(ClientRect);
    end else NewBackColor := clWhite;

  for I:=1 to Length(Text) do begin
   if PasswordChar=#0 then begin
     if Text[I] in ['0'..'9'] then begin
       NewColor := clRed;
       DrawEx(Text[I]);
      end else begin
       NewColor := clGreen;
       DrawEx(Text[I]);
      end;
     Inc(R.Left,Canvas.TextWidth(Text[I]));
    end else begin //with passwordchar
       NewColor := clBlack;
       DrawEx(PasswordChar);
     Inc(R.Left,Canvas.TextWidth(PasswordChar));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another small improvement by overriding the CreateParams procedure which fixes the flickering during text selection (mouse move while left button down):

```
procedure TMyEdit.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
    inherited;
    if csDesigning in ComponentState then
        exit;
    Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
end;
```